# Checking user password on Android

Tags: java, cryptography, passwords, pbkdf2

I'm writing a utility class for password security for an Android app I'm working on. Currently, it generates a salt, then generates a hash using that salt and the password as parameters. I need a method that compares the hash stored in the database to the hash that is created when the user attempts to sign in. Should I compare the two byte arrays using `Arrays.equals()`? 
Or should I take in a `byte[] dbHash`, `String password`, and `byte[] salt` as parameters and go from there?

Here's the code so far.

```
package fitfast.security;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

public final class Authenticator {

    private static final int length = 512;
    private static final int iterations = 60000;

    public static byte[] generateHash(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512";
        KeySpec sp = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, length);
        SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        return kf.generateSecret(sp).getEncoded();
    }

    public static byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

    public static boolean check(byte[] hash, String password, byte[] salt) {

        //code goes here

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that `Arrays.equals()` would be the way to go. Something like

```
public static boolean check(byte[] hash, String password, byte[] salt) {

   return Arrays.equals(hash, generateHash(password,salt));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the chance is very slim, but an attacker may be able to exploit the way [`Arrays.equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#2685) compares two hashes. The function works iteratively and returns as soon as a differing byte is found. An attacker might try different passwords and observe different response times. This would mean that the first bytes of the hash matched (assuming PBKDF2 takes always the same time). This could be repeated multiple times until a matching password is brute forced.

There are multiple ways of comparing arrays in a time-constant manner. I like XORing each byte of the two arrays and ORing the resulting byte array into a single byte. If that byte is 0 then the two arrays were equal:

```
public static boolean check(byte[] hash, String password, byte[] salt) {
    byte[] generatedHash = generateHash(password,salt);
    byte result = (byte)0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
        result |= hash[i] ^ generatedHash[i];
    }
    return result == (byte)0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I've read about that being a potential issue. Thank you for the advice!